# Extra margin appearing in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have been building my user interface in Android Studio using ConstraintLayouts. However I have got an issue where I am getting some mystery extra margin at the bottom of a child ConstraintLayout that throws everything out of alignment.

As you can see in this gif, as soon as I constrain the EditText to the ImageView a large margin appears at the bottom of the ConstraintLayout. I cannot seem to figure out why this is happening.

[image]

As a result of this, as soon as I constrain any other ConstraintLayouts to the dodgy ConstraintLayout, all the alignments go wrong and elements are no longer centered, as shown in the gif below.

[image]

Here is the code for the entire layout (the dodgy form has id 'createTaskViewFormContainer'):

[link to gist of code](https://gist.github.com/CallumCoombes/6075545bbea2465d8a400088ee39ca4a)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:background="#E8ECEE"
    tools:context="apps.cal.lonesafe.CreateTaskFragment.CreateTaskView">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/createTaskViewFormContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewTeamName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="New Task"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewLabelIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_label_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewTaskNameEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewTaskNameEditText" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewTaskNameEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_alignment_background_grey"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:hint="Task Name"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewLabelIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewTeamName" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewClockIcon"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_clock_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewTimePickerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewTimePickerTextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewTimePickerTextView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_alignment_background_grey"
            android:elevation="2dp"
            android:text="00h 00m"
            android:textColor="#94989a"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewTaskNameEditText"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewClockIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewTaskNameEditText" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewRecordMessageButton"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_blue_roundsquare"
            android:text="Record Message"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewTimePickerTextView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/createTaskViewClockIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewTimePickerTextView" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/createTaskViewTeamSettingsLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewPanicButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewStartButton">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsFirstPinIcon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_mic_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsSecondPinIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsSecondPinIcon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="11.5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_checkin_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsThirdPinIcon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="11.5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_pin_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsPinIconCentreView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsFifthPinIcon"
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_alert_pin_32dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsThirdPinIcon"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsThirdPinIcon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/createTaskViewGuardianSettingsThirdPinIcon" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createTaskViewStartButton"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_blue_roundsquare"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:text="Start Task"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/createTaskViewFormContainer" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/createTaskViewPanicButton"
        style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_red_roundsquare_unfocused"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:text="Request Help"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/voiceRecordOverlayLayout"
        layout="@layout/overlay_voice_record"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/teamSettingsOverlayLayout"
        layout="@layout/overlay_team_settings"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/submitCreateTaskOverlayLayout"
        layout="@layout/overlay_submit_create_task"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/updatingTeamRulesOverlayLayout"
        layout="@layout/overlay_updating_team_rules"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Is there something wrong with how I have setup my layout?

I am out of ideas on how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced this behaviour using `ConstraintLayout 1.0.2`. However, just changing the dependency in the gradle file to the latest version (`1.1.0-beta6`)

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0-beta6'
```

automatically solved the issue without any changes to the XML. The unnecessary space disappeared and the views are positioned correctly.